# Is it possible to set top border on ChartJS Doughnut Gauge chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

**Target Doughnut gauge with green top border**:

[image]

**Example Doughnut gauge**: https://codesandbox.io/s/jlonjk9zv5

**The question**: Is it possible to implement abovementioned top green border on given example Doughnut gauge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're using the really old version 2.7.3 of Chart.js. With this version, it is probably not possible to do what you're looking for. You should first upgrade Chart.js (current latest version is 3.7.1).

In order to make the fewest changes to your code, I updated the version to 2.9.4 (latest available 2.n version) and simply added a second dataset with a lower `weight` than the base dataset.

Please take a look at your amended code here at [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-gauge-example-forked-4sx5zh?file=/src/index.js) and see how it works.